# How to collect only number from a string and construct a list of them?

Tags: vba

I have a column of cells like: [[[3,0, [5.0, 6.0]], [6.0, 6,0], [3.0, [6.0, 5.0]]]
How do I break its string so that each numeric value from that cell would be appended to a list/array with VBA?

Comment: Iterate through the column.  Replace the `[` and `]` with `""`.  Then split on the `,`.  Iterate through the split string adding each part to your array.

Comment: I get that but is it possible to have them in a list where it would be possible to tell how they were enclosed by brackets, i.e. the output for my case would be:
array=("3.0", "5.0, 6.0", "6.0, 6.0", "3.0", "6.0, 5.0")
I understand if this is too much, I've trying various loops all day

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below example:

```
Sub Test()

    q = "[[[3.0, [5.0, 6.0]], [6.0, 6.0], [3.0, [6.0, 5.0]]]"
    Do
        w = Len(q)
        q = Replace(q, "[[", "[")
        q = Replace(q, "]]", "]")
    Loop Until w = Len(q)
    q = Replace(q, "], [", "|")
    q = Replace(q, ", [", "|")
    q = Replace(q, "],", "|")
    q = Mid(q, 2, Len(q) - 2)
    a = Split(q, "|")

End Sub
```

The resulting array:

[image: locals]